# Add to .ps1 files Run with PowerShell As Administrator

Tags: command-line, bash, powershell

hello i have this reg script to add keys to run powershell in directory as administrator ...
but i need add this option to file with extension ".ps1" ... what i need add???

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\OpenElevatedPS]
@="Open PowerShell here as administrator"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\OpenElevatedPS\command]
@="PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -Command \"Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/s,/c,pushd %V && powershell' -Verb RunAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\OpenElevatedPS]
@="Open PowerShell here as administrator"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\OpenElevatedPS\command]
@="PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -Command \"Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/s,/c,pushd %V && powershell' -Verb RunAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\OpenElevatedPS]
@="Open PowerShell here as administrator"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\OpenElevatedPS\command]
@="PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -Command \"Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/s,/c,pushd %V && powershell' -Verb RunAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\OpenElevatedPS]
@="Open PowerShell here as administrator"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\OpenElevatedPS\command]
@="PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -Command \"Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/s,/c,pushd %V && powershell' -Verb RunAs\""
```

**Update**

i try to use this but not work correctly:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\shell\OpenElevatedPS]
@="Ejecutar con PowerShell como Administrador"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\shell\OpenElevatedPS\command]
@="PowerShell -Command \"Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/s,/c,pushd %V && powershell' -Verb RunAs\""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it run for a file extension you would typically need to add a variable for the filename that is passed, `%1`,

However i think there are easier solutions available. please see [here](https://winaero.com/blog/run-as-administrator-context-menu-for-power-shell-ps1-files/)

Excerpt: Save as powershellrunas.reg and double click it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\runas\command]
@="powershell.exe \"-Command\" \"if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'\""
```